# Magento 2.3 Unable to inject classes in __construct in Magento/Ups/Model/Carrier.php

Tags: magento2.3, ups

I have overridden the `Magento/Ups/Model/Carrier.php` to `Custom/Module/Model/Carrier.php` successfully. 
I need a cart quote from it, so I have inject the class in constructor.

When I add to cart a product and go to cart page the error:

> Type Error occurred when creating object: Custom\Module\Model\Carrier, Argument 16 passed to Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface, array given, called in /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Carrier.php on line 56

Adding the __construct() doesn't work in my custom module.

`Custom/Module/Model/Carrier.php`

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Module\Model;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Error;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrierOnline;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Simplexml\Element;
use Magento\Ups\Helper\Config;
use Magento\Framework\Xml\Security;

class Carrier extends \Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier
{
    protected $_cart;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory 
    $rateErrorFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    Security $xmlSecurity,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Simplexml\ElementFactory $xmlElFactory,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateFactory,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory 
    $rateMethodFactory,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\ResultFactory $trackFactory,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\ErrorFactory 
     $trackErrorFactory,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\StatusFactory 
    $trackStatusFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory $regionFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryData,
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface 
       $stockRegistry,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
    array $data = [],
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
    )
    {
    $this->_cart = $cart;
    parent::__construct(
        $scopeConfig,
        $rateErrorFactory,
        $logger,
        $xmlSecurity,
        $xmlElFactory,
        $rateFactory,
        $rateMethodFactory,
        $trackFactory,
        $trackErrorFactory,
        $trackStatusFactory,
        $regionFactory,
        $countryFactory,
        $currencyFactory,
        $directoryData,
        $stockRegistry,
        $data
    );
    $this->_localeFormat = $localeFormat;
    }


    protected function _parseCgiResponse($response)
    {
    //my custom logic goes here
    //get cart quote here
    return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you saw?  Did you perform a `di:compile` (required when changing/adding constructor parameters)

Comment: all commands run correctly but when I add to cart a product and go to cart page it give error like this:Type Error occurred when creating object: Custom\Module\Model\Carrier, Argument 16 passed to Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface, array given, called in /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Carrier.php on line 56 [] []

Comment: I also need to ask, is it good practice to add Object Manager directly ,as the original class has objectmanager already defined in construct ?

Comment: did you try to clear `generated/code` and `generated/metadata`?

Comment: @DineshRajput you can "get" the object manager at any time regardless of if it being passed in a constructor - `$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();`.  And no in general it is not the best practice, using the constructor parameters is.

Comment: @Marius I have cleared those generated/code and generated/meta and still showing same error.

Comment: Remove the construct and direct override function and check it.

Comment: @DhadukMitesh Without __construct its already working fine. I need a cart quote by injecting in construct. Kindly please read the question again.

Comment: Have you tried an observer instead?

Comment: I need to change UPS rates based on cart subtotal/freeshipping applied at checkout. So have to work inside _parseCgiResponse function() for UPS rates. I have already applied my logic using object manager and its working fine. So, I am facing error only while injecting any single class by __construct

Comment: Change position of `\Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,` and `array $data = [],` in construct and check it.

Comment: I have tried but still not working. Giving error argument 19 "AsyncClientInterface" is null in system.log.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you are not implementing the interface 100% or that `setup:di:compile` was not run after you did.  I can check with Magento 2.3.3 and I see that you are missing the last 4 parameters:

```
Config $configHelper,
ClientFactory $httpClientFactory,
array $data = [],
?AsyncClientInterface $asyncHttpClient = null,
?ProxyDeferredFactory $proxyDeferredFactory
```

Please check your version of magento, if 2.3.3 then changing the last parameters of the construct (i.e. after `\Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,`) should fix it...

```
Config $configHelper,
ClientFactory $httpClientFactory,
array $data = [],
?AsyncClientInterface $asyncHttpClient = null,
?ProxyDeferredFactory $proxyDeferredFactory,
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
```

Comment: I haven't used because in main original class the methods are private methods. e.g. private $asyncHttpClient;

Comment: Can you pls post full code ? its still not working

Comment: please confirm exact version of magento

Comment: My version of Magento is 2.3.3